# Azure AD B2C Custom policy SAML token lifetime & session timeout

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I configured a custom b2c policy for the sign-up/sign-in flow that uses SAML for token exchange.
I would like to understand how to control the token lifetime (SAML) and session duration.

The session duration should be 4 hours, to prevent the user from continuing to re-enter credentials I would like to be able to configure an idle timeout so that the session is disconnected if there is no interaction.

Also I would like if the user closes the browser without logging out, when reopened it will prompt for credentials

Is all of this possible? At the moment I'm not using offline_access scope on app registration.
[offline_access scope app registration not enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nzda2.png)

At the moment I have only tried putting this in my RP file:

```
  <RelyingParty>
    <DefaultUserJourney ReferenceId="SignUpOrSignInMFAOption" />
    <UserJourneyBehaviors> 
        <SingleSignOn Scope="Application" /> 
        <SessionExpiryType>Rolling</SessionExpiryType> 
        <SessionExpiryInSeconds>900</SessionExpiryInSeconds> 
    </UserJourneyBehaviors>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="PolicyProfile">
      <DisplayName>PolicyProfile</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="SAML2" />
```

Answer (score 0):

**Control the token lifetime (SAML) and session duration**

To define a session duration for SAML you could use "TokenLifeTimeInSeconds" in Saml2AssertionIssuer technical profile metadata.

[image: Assertion profile metadata]

As per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/saml-issuer-technical-profile#metadata TokenLifeTimeInSeconds specifies the life of the SAML Assertion. This value is in seconds from the NotBefore value referenced above. The default value is 300 seconds (5 Min).

**I would like if the user closed the browser without logging out, when reopened it will prompt for credentials**

This could be achieved for local accounts only by removing /excluding Keep me signed in (KMSI) claim, when you enable the feature, users can opt to stay signed in, so the session remains active after they close the browser. The reference sample could be found https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/unit-tests/blob/main/session/Session_KeepAliveInDays.xml

Also, the SAML IDP metadata should have ForceAuthN set to true

Passes the ForceAuthN value in the SAML authentication request to determine if the external SAML IDP will be forced to prompt the user for authentication. By default, Azure AD B2C sets the ForceAuthN value to false on initial login. If the session is then reset (for example by using the prompt=login in OIDC) then the ForceAuthN value will be set to true. Setting the metadata item as shown below will force the value for all requests to the external IDP. Possible values: true or false. Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/saml-identity-provider-technical-profile#metadata

Comment: Hi @mavric20 
I have not really understand the forceauthn parameter, the fact that the user has to re-authenticate when closing the browser is because I did not put the offline_access scope in api permissions.

I am using local account azure ad b2c which is also idp, to adjust the session and make it expire after a certain period of inactivity how can i do?